# Specific font family inside a form in PHP

Tags: php, css, forms, fonts, font-family

I am creating an enquiry form in PHP, using a form I created in HTML. Is it possible to use a specfic font inside the PHP code like you can in HTML? for example:

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">

font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
```

Below you can see my PHP code I'm referring to:

```
$email_to = "billy.farroll@hotmail.com";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$tel = $_POST["tel"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];

$email_from = "billy@slickfin.com"; // This email address has to be the same email on the server if using Fasthots server i.e. SlickFin server - billy@SlickFin.com you can't put the $email variable entered by user because its not authorised to send it.
$message = $_POST["message"];
$email_subject = "Enquiry";
```

For example, this section (below) I want to use the `font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;` for the email I receive when the form has been filled and submitted. THIS IS MY QUESTION.

```
$headers =   
"From: $email .\n";   
"Reply-To: $email .\n"; // 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";  
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= "<h1 style='color: #0d1237;'>Enquiry</h1>";
$message .= "<h2 style='color: #0d1237; font-size: 22px;'> Name: " . $name . "</h1>";
$message .= "<p style='font-weight: bold;'> Email Address: " . $email . "</p>";
$message .= "<p style='font-weight: bold;'> Telephone Number: " . $tel . "</p>"; 
$message .= "<p style='font-weight: bold;'> Message: " . $msg ."</p>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
```

Also, here's my HTML form code:

```
<section id="contact">
    <form action="enquiry.php" method="post">
          <div class="field name-box">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Who Are You?" tabindex="1" required>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <span>Done</span>
          </div>

          <div class="field email-box">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@email.com" tabindex="2" required>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <span>Done</span>
          </div>

      <div class="field tel-box">
                <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telephone Number" tabindex="3" required>
                <label for="tel">Mobile</label>
                <span>Done</span>
          </div>

          <div class="field msg-box">
                <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="4" placeholder="What's Up?" tabindex="1" required></textarea>
                <label for="msg">Message</label>
                <span>Done</span>
          </div>

          <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
```

If you'd like to see the entire index.html and the entire equiry.php files, you can via Github at: https://github.com/billyfarroll/enquiry_slick_one

Comment: You could write that font-family setting into the HTML tags as a style attribute as you did with the other settings. However, the recepient of that email would have to have that font installed on his/her computer. If not, the displayed font would fall back to the standard sans-serif font of that system. I don't think HTML email allows fetching a font for example from googlefonts or similar, as you can do it in a webpage.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. That was my main query to see if there was any possible way to import the specific font-family into the enquiry.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not an output format. PHP might manipulate the output, but it is not the output itself. Think about PHP as a calculator and HTML as the numbers on the calculator screen. Your question doesn't really make sense.

There are many different output formats. [HTML](https://www.w3.org/html/) is just one of them and is probably what you'll be working with mostly other than [JSON](https://www.json.org/).

It seems in this case you're sending an HTML email. Most email clients will display HTML and CSS; similar to a web browser. What you're going to want to do is **use** PHP to **generate** some CSS (an output format) and HTML (Also an output format) to get the result you want.

The CSS in your HTML emails is more limited than what you can do in a browser. To ensure compatibility **in this particular case**, I recommend using [inline styles](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/) in order to get your desired effect.

To add a font to your HTML email that you're not expecting the client to have, you could also do something like this...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Lato';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://some-site/email.woff) format('woff');
    }
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
</html>
```

Note that this will work with some email clients, and not with others...so make sure to use some fallback fonts in your CSS.

Comment: I appreciate that PHP is not an output format and that it only manipulates the output (dependant on what the user inputs). But in my PHP code, where you can see the $message variable, I have used inline styles here, but was curious to know if there was anyway of changing the font that is outputted in the mail delivered? What you're saying is there isn't anyway of changing the font delivered in the mail?

Comment: @billy.farroll You can use inline css to change the font.

Comment: @billy.farroll As far as the HTML goes, using PHP to insert something like what I added in my answer into your HTML email would work.

Comment: Perfect, so basically you're declaring the font i.e. Lato in your HTML rather than importing it from external src i.e. Google Fonts. So the PHP can understand the font-family you use in the inline style?

Comment: @billy.farroll No. If you looks at my code (`src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://some-site/email.woff) format('woff');`) I am still fetching the font from an external source. Again, some email clients will allow this, and other wont, so it's important to pick a fallback font that you expect all clients to have locally.

Comment: Ok, great. Easily understandable. Thanks for the advice.